# How can I tell which application is using the network?

Tags: network

Very occasionally when using my Mac, I notice my internet connection slowing down. Using Activity Monitor I can see that it's because something is downloading data at the full rate my connection can support --- but I don't know how to tell what's responsible for it. It can be caused by several different things (Dropbox syncing; some app doing an automatic update; most recently it was a video buffering in a browser tab that I'd forgotten about) so it'd be really handy to have a way to tell which app is responsible for the network use. Is such a thing possible in OS X? Ideally I'm looking for a free solution. (Command line is OK.) I'm on Snow Leopard if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this `dtrace` one-liner:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::recvfrom:return { @[pid,execname] = sum(arg0); }'
```

Let it run for a while, then hit Control-C. It will print a summary of the number of bytes read from sockets, distributed among processes. For a more detailed view, replace `sum` by `quantize`. Or just to see a count of socket reads, replace `sum` by `count`.

Disclaimer: I have only tried this on Lion, but AFAIK no great changes in dtrace-ability have occured between SL and Lion.

Comment: Many thanks! Simple and effective and does exactly what I needed. Works just fine on Snow Leopard.

Comment: ...although actually, using "sum" the numbers look a bit odd - Google Chrome usually gets a negative number (!). But using quantize they look sensible.

Comment: Negative numbers, huh? Maybe it's a case of overflow. Or if you get small negative numbers, remember that system calls return -1 if an error occured. If it's overflow, my guess is that it wouldn't happen when you run a 64 bit kernel.

Comment: They're medium-sized negative numbers. Here's a typical output (taken while re-loading this page in Chrome):

       250  Google Chrome           -159
;
       39  KernelEventAgen          1
;
       19  mDNSResponder            2240
;
but I might just be misinterpreting them - when I use 'quanitze' there's a "value" column which can have a negative values, and a "count" column. It looks like the sum command reports the sum of (value)*(count). Maybe negative values mean incoming packets, or something?

Comment: No, this is all about incoming data … I guess that chrome does frequent polling by calling recvfrom with a short timeout set in the socket, in which case the return value -1 results if there is no data. See the manual page for recvfrom.

Comment: Just aliased this to 'netwkapps'. Thank you for making my life easier! I am using it (at the moment) to determine if I can safely set my computer for no sleep close it up and go home and let it finish on the way (flash storage so no bouncing HD issues :D)... unfortunately the answer is no...

Answer (score 6):

### Firewalls

You could use **[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)** or **[HandsOff](http://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/)**. They are great firewalls and both have a "Network Monitor" feature, that will do the job:

> **Little Snitch** includes a Network Monitor, showing detailed information of all incoming and outgoing network traffic.
> A status icon in the menu bar provides a summary of current network activity, and a monitor window with more comprehensive information pops up automatically in case of new traffic events.
>
> **Hands Off** is an application to monitor and control the access of applications to your network and disks. Being able to monitor the normally unnoticeable activities enables you to make informed decisions regarding the transfer of your private information, hence avoiding confidential information leakage.

[image] [image]

<sup>The network monitors of: **Little Snitch** (left), **HandsOff** (right)</sup>

### Nettop

A free and built-in cli solution (unfortunately it is not included in Snow Leopard) would be [nettop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/nettop.1.html). nettop groups traffic by program and port and measures various network statistics.

### Other

There are few other programs, that capture and measure traffic ([iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/), [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [tcpdump](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html)), but they don't know the originated pid. To make the connection you should use [netstat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I've edited the question to indicate that I'm ideally looking for a free solution (€30 is too much for something I'd use only very occasionally), but if there isn't a free way to do it then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll try to find a free alternative and will update my answer.

Comment: Ha! `nettop` was new to me. Looks handy.

Comment: I'd accept this answer too if it were possible. If I upgrade to Lion it looks like nettop will be really handy.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo fs_usage -f network
```

will give you all network accesses by all applications (and processes). Usually the process creating a lot of traffic is the one which appears most often in the output.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I'm impressed by the number of helpful answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The "DTrace book" has a script, [soconnect.d](http://www.dtracebook.com/index.php/Network_Lower_Level_Protocols%3asoconnect.d), that does this.

Copy the "Mac OS X" version, paste it in a text file, then run it from the terminal with `sudo dtrace -s soconnect.d`.

Comment: But that does not give you a notion of the amount of network traffic a process receives does it? It only tracks connections, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Monitor has also had columns for received and sent bytes since 10.9:

[image]